# How to Ignore specifc element value using value-of

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Below my input

```
<root>
<text>
 <bold>Co<csc>lorado DivIs</csc>IoN</bold>
</text>
<text>
 fi<csc>ve and a ha</csc>lf <x>abc</x>
</text>
</root>
```

Here is my xslt my implemntation (xslt verions-1.0)

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/text">
    <xsl:value-of select="./child::*[local-name(.)!='x']" />
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

correct output look like below, should ignore only 'x' element value.

```
Colorado DivIsIoN five and a half
```

The output I am getting is with missing current element text.

```
 Colorado DivIsIoN ve and a ha
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text/x"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">

      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have four templates; two of them don't do anything.

Comment: first to match root, second to ignore x, third to match node and 4th just to get text. lease let me know if i'm making any flaw in writing code like this, as i'm not that proficient in XSLT. Thanks

Comment: Root is a node, so it is already matched by the third template. And the third template does not output anything. Your second and fourth templates are doing all the work here.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/text">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//text()[not (parent::x)]">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! it is not working if element having with dot for example my element is footnote.reference. you are using parent key word and mye element can occure any where inside <text> it may be child or sub child.

Comment: then use `ancestor::x` instead of `parent::x`

Comment: @RupeshDasari I am not sure I understand your example. If Joel's suggestion doesn't work for you, please edit your question and post an example of the troublesome input.

Comment: Thanks Joel ancestor is working and thank for follow up michael